# Convert image from pygame to PIL image

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library, webcam-capture

we are using a **Raspberry Pi + Python 3.4 + PyGame** to capture an image from a specific USB webcam. We use this simple code to capture (it works ok):

```
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0],(1280,720))
cam.start()
time.sleep(1)
webcamImage = cam.get_image()
```

The problem comes here: we have to convert this *webcamImage* into a PIL image. We follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176689/how-to-convert-a-pygame-surface-to-a-pil-image) link but unfortunately the function Image.fromstring() not exists anymore. So, **we can't do that**:

```
pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(webcamImage, "RGBA",False)
pil_image = Image.fromstring("RGBA",(1280,720),pil_string_image)
```

PIL says that Image.fromstring() is deprecated, and suggests to use the function *Image.frombytes()*. Clearly we not found the equivalent pygame.image function that convert the webcamImage into an array of bytes. So we are stucked here: can you help us, please?
Thank you :-)

Comment: What is the actual type of the result of `pygame.image.tostring()`? In other words, what does `type(pil_string_image).__name__` produce? If `bytes`, then the Pygame documentation is outdated. If `str` then I'll need more help to discern the encoding that Pygame is applying.

Comment: Hy @DamianYerrick, first of all: thank you for your gentle reply. We follow your suggest, so we do that: print(type(pil_string_image).__name__) and the result is **bytes**. So, what you suggest to do?

Comment: Ok, we answer ourself down here (:-D)

Answer (score 4):

As per Damian Yerrick's comment, under Python 3 the result of `pygame.image.tostring()` is a `bytes`, despite the method's name. Thus we can go out of this situation with this simple code:

```
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0],(1280,720))
cam.start()
time.sleep(1)
webcamImage = cam.get_image()
pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(webcamImage,"RGBA",False)
im = Image.frombytes("RGBA",(1280,720),pil_string_image)
```

Comment: what is `img`?  Perhaps it should be `pil_string_image = pygame.image.tostring(webcamImage,"RGBA",False)`?

Comment: our **img** is what you call **webcamImage**. Thank you for your answer but we solved 1 year ago our question.

Comment: It was a great question and answer. I upvoted both. By the way do you know how to show those PIL images (in the raspberry)?

Comment: Hello, our needs were to acquire an image and save it into a file. You can try these lines of code (warning: we don't try that code):

from PIL import Image | img = Image.open('test.png') | img.show()