# How to get grayscale image using YUV image Pygame

Tags: pygame, grayscale, yuv

I am trying to learn Pygame and I wanted to start from something simple. I just stuck on eliminating U and V channel from image to get a grayscale image.

```
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(self.clist[0], self.size, "YUV")
```

What is the way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the PIL/pillow library, you can convert the pygame image into a PIL image, perform the grayscale conversion there, and convert back. This conversion is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463717/convert-image-from-pygame-to-pil-image/35464398). Alternatively, you can just use the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693616/2588654) that manually transforms the data to grayscale.

Comment: Thank you for help the second link works fine but is there a way to do that if you recording the picture as YUV format

Comment: With YUV, the Y component is the luminance, so you can use that for the R, G, and B components of the surface array. If R = G = B, you should get a grayscale image, so just make Y = R = G = B.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @user2588654